# Migrate Neo4j data to GrapheneDB

Tags: neo4j

So I’m ready to move my Neo4j database from my local machine to GrapheneDB for further development.

How can I move the data on my local machine to the GrapheneDB remote store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm one of the founders at [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com).

Moving your data from your local machine to GrapheneDB is simple:

1. Stop your local instance: `$ bin/neo4j stop`
2. Put the contentes in a tarball or other type of compressed file (zip, gz): `tar -cjf graph.tar.bz2 data/graph.db`
3. Sign up or log in to GrapheneDB and create your database instance
4. Once the DB is created, navigate to the admin and use the restore feature to upload your compressed store files

Notes:

- Neo4j should be stopped before copying your store files into a compressed file
- You should restore into the same or a higher version on GrapheneDB, i.e. 2.0.X into 2.1.X or 2.1.6 into 2.1.6.

I hope this helps.

If you have any issues let us know. You can also contact our support once you've signed up through [support UI](https://app.graphenedb.com/support/tickets/new) or by emailing support at graphenedb dot com.

Comment: I’m sure this would be the right answer so I marked it so. I just ended up reusing my test php scripts to add data, and data not included I’m not really missing out on. Thanks though

Comment: Great. Glad everything worked out well either way. ;)